# css layout - break down

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to get the effect of having two frames inside a 750px wide frame.

```
.news {width: 750px;}
.news1 {width:550px;}
.news2 {width:200px;}
```

Very simple css at this stage.

The html/php:

```
            <div class="news">
            <div class="format"><a href='newspiece.php?news=<?echo $id?>'><?echo "$subject\n";?></a></div>
                <div class="news1">
                    <?
                    echo "<div class='content'>";
                    echo nl2br($comment);
                    echo "<a href='newspiece.php?news=$id'>..[read more]..</a>\n";
                    echo "</div>";
                    ?>
                    <h5><? echo "Posted by <a href=\"userprofile.php?user=$posted\">$posted</a> on $final_date\n";?></h5>
                    <? echo "<br />\n";?>
                </div>
                <div class="news2">
                    <img src="images/news/<? echo $id?>.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>]
```

THe problem I am getting is that the image that should be on the right is going underneath. So in effect, news1 is above news2, rather than side by side.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
.news1, .news2 {float: left}
```

Comment: I'd also suggest floating the parent container of `news1` and `news2`. `.format {float: left;}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `float` property on the divs:

```
.news1 {width:550px; float: left;}
.news2 {width:200px; float: right;}
```